# i want to search the database of what the user entered and display all the possible occurrence of the word

Tags: c#, sql, database, connection-string

```
    public string[] ResultsQuery;
    public int i;
    public string criteria;
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {


        string connString = @"Data Source=ITLAPTOP\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=trial;Integrated Security=True";
        SqlConnection connStudent = new SqlConnection(connString);
        connStudent.Open();

        if (Request.QueryString[TextBox1.Text] != null)
        {
            ResultsQuery = Request.QueryString[TextBox1.Text].Split(' ');


            foreach (string textbox1 in ResultsQuery)
            {
                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(criteria))
                    criteria += "  OR ";

                criteria += "SearchName LIKE '%" + textbox1 + "%' ";
            }

            string SqlInsertStatement = @"select * from trial.dbo.Student where Student.SearchName where '" + criteria;
            SqlCommand cmdTxt = new SqlCommand(SqlInsertStatement, connStudent);
            SqlDataReader dtrACode = cmdTxt.ExecuteReader();
            dtrACode.Read();


            try
            {
                if ((dtrACode["SearchName"].ToString().Trim().Length != 0))
                {

                }
                ListBox1.Items.Add(dtrACode["SearchName"].ToString());
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                ListBox1.Items.Add("NO RECORD FOUND!");


            }


            connStudent.Close();
            connStudent.Dispose();
        }
    }
```

i want to display all occurrence of the keyword the user input, for example
list in database:
abCARdfg
CARsdg
CAR
dfgsd
sdkgs

== when i search the word CAR all the string with CAR should be displayed and dfgsd,sdkgs will not be displayed

the query is working just like what i was expecting the SQL server to display but i dont know where to place it in the code in c#, and when i click the button it does not display anything even the NO RECORD FOUND which serves as a error handler

Comment: Debug your code and put a break point on the line `string SqlInsertStatement`, then step past that line and capture the value in the variable `SqlInsertStatement`. Copy and paste that query into SQL Server Management Studio and run it, I am betting that you will get an error. Finally, post that query in your question and help will arrive. :-)

Comment: Hope no one types `%' DROP DATABASE trial --` in the TextBox :p

Comment: i tried to debug it and placed several break points, it only reaches this line "if (Request.QueryString[TextBox1.Text] != null)" and stops

Comment: So that means that there is nothing in the querystring. Just curious why you need to lookup from the querystring. Why can't you use TextBox1.Text

Comment: it is now working buy the problem is it only displays the first occurrence of the keyword. example: database: abCARdfg CARsdg CAR dfgsd sdkgs when i type CAR it only displays abCARdfg, it must display all :(

Comment: First of all, for your own safety, recode because sql injection is a HUGE issue in your sample. As @sa_ddam213 said... Then, check the dtrACode.Read() it only reads one record, you have to use a loop to read the whole Recordset

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since I dont have access to your code, my best guess is that you have an error with the following line:

```
string SqlInsertStatement = @"select * from trial.dbo.Student where Student.SearchName where '" + criteria;
```

Replace that with the following:

```
   string SqlInsertStatement = @"select * from trial.dbo.Student where " + criteria;
```

Comment: Try adding a break point on the 'string SqlInsertStatement' line, and see what SQL is being executed. I am suspecting that its not picking up your search word - eg CAR

Comment: theres nothing, yeah i also think it is not picking up the search word.

Comment: i tried to debug it and placed several break points, it only reaches this line "if (Request.QueryString[TextBox1.Text] != null)" and stops

Comment: it is now working buy the problem is it only displays the first occurrence of the keyword. example: database: abCARdfg CARsdg CAR dfgsd sdkgs when i type CAR it only displays abCARdfg, it must display all :(

Answer (score 0):

Remove the try/catch and post the details of the Exception that is thrown. There is definately an error in your query. For example, you repeat a "where".

```
where Student.SearchName where
```

Also, your code has SQL injection vulnerability in that the textbox1 value can contain anything and is not escaped. For example, a person can type '; -- delete from TABLE; 
and delete everything in your table...